# Is there a way to change the VB_PredeclaredId Attribute to False for VBA User Forms

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

After reading about userform best practices in VBA *(credit to Mat's Mug)* in the now discontinued SO documentation site *(posting new links to SO Documentation is disallowed)* I thought it would be a good idea to set `Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False` for the userforms in my project.

I figured this would provide a practical way to enforce the concept of using a new instance of the userform each time instead of using the default instance.

For a class module it is possible to set the VB_PredeclaredID attribute to True, I had anticipated being able to do the opposite: export the userform, change the attribute to False, then import the modified version.

Sadly whenever I import the modified userform the attribute automatically (and annoyingly) reverts to True.

```
VERSION 5.00
Begin {C62A69F0-16DC-11CE-9E98-00AA00574A4F} UserForm1 
   Caption         =   "UserForm1"
   ClientHeight    =   3165
   ClientLeft      =   45
   ClientTop       =   390
   ClientWidth     =   4710
   OleObjectBlob   =   "UserForm1.frx":0000
   StartUpPosition =   1  'CenterOwner
End
Attribute VB_Name = "UserForm1"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False        ' <<<<< Keeps changing back to True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
```

**So, the question:**

Is there a setting or some other thing that I can do to force the VB_PredeclaredId attribute of a userform to stay False?

[Edit: I'm using MS Word, would hope the answer is equally applicable to Excel]

Comment: No, not that I am aware of. You'll just have to be diligent. ;)

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried it in Excel (2016) and it behaved the same:  Reset it on import.

Comment: @Rory I admit that I'm expecting there to be a way, still a bit surprised that the attribute is reset :-/

Comment: @ainwood thanks for testing :)

Comment: @Rory FYI workaround below

Comment: You most certainly *don't* want a form to have no predeclared ID - the default instance is the single cleanest place to put a factory method IMO, and this defeats the whole "VBA classes can't have a parameterized constructor" argument! =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug you know, this is the interesting thing about learning... Learner has an idea that something is bad *(like self destructing userforms)* and wants to avoid it but doesn't know how... Oh, a Factory you say!  As OOP concepts are becoming increasingly meaningful for me I actually understand what you're saying here *(in a way that I wouldn't have when I first asked the question)* - thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## A workaround that seems to suit my needs

The approach is based on this article by @MatsMug: [userform1.show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/).

In my userForm I add the following:

```
'@Folder("UI.Forms")

Option Explicit

Implements IView

Const ERR_MODEL As String = "This userForm requires a view model (which is not set)"

Private Type TView
    IsCancelled As Boolean
    Model As frmModel
    toDisplay As String
End Type

Private this As TView

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    If this.Model Is Nothing Then
        Err.Raise Number:=91, Description:=ERR_MODEL
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub
```

The `_Activate` event checks if the model is set - if not an error is raised.

Initially I tried to complete this check in the `_Initialize` event, but that is actually too soon as the form is Initialized before the model is set.